# VECTORWORKS : superpostion in 3D, transparent walls, display unreadable

Tags: display, 3d-modeling, architecture, vectorworks

I have a problem to display my 3D project on vectorworks. The walls are like hollow and transparent (image 1, transparent walls), and the whole becomes very diffcult to read and understand, as you can see on this picture :  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMLDW.png)

This is an exemple of what I'm tring to do (with thick and opaque walls) : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLwlH.png)

Thank you for the help

Comment: Vectorworks' recommended system requirements mention, regarding the graphics card, *a dedicated OpenGL 2.1 compatible graphics card with 4GB of VRAM or more*.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved.
It was because there was an object very far away from the origin and VW was creating an aberration.